# turn off wysiwyg for full html filter format?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

How do i set it so that the wysiwyg doesn't turn on during full html mode.

I would prefer to hand edit the html during full html filter mode without the wysiwyg editor stripping my html.

I'm using CKEditor.

Comment: Which version of ckeditor?  7.x-1.x or 7.x-2.x?

Comment: the latest so probably 7.x-2.x

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to HTML display in D8 by clicking on source tab. So that you can retain Full HTML processing and work without output. [image: Source Tab]

Answer (score 0):

Set your input format to 'Full HTML', edit away, and save. When you come back to the page, it will be in 'Full HTML' format. If, however, you switch it back to Wysiwyg, you will lose your html formatting. Don't switch it back.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can navigate to `admin/config/content/ckeditor` there you can see different profiles, there are to profiles which are added by ckeditor called "Advanced" and "Full".
The full profile is the one used when you switch to "Full HTML" you can delete this profile or if you want to keep it, then you can edit it and uncheck "Full HTML" from its list.

in this case when you switch to Full HTML the ckeditor won't show up any more.